# How to handle a tabular data in a report file using pandas when the data is not dumped in a fixed width way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I came across `read_fwf` in pandas which allows to read tabular data from columns separated by fixed width in a text file.

In my file, the value for a field in a record is written in the next line when the value for the preceding field is very big. see below :  Email for record 1 is long so that Phone for the same record is written in the next line.

How can I load it in pandas ?

```
str_test = """
--------------------------------------------------------
 Name       Address         Email                  Phone    
---------------------------------------------------------   
 Andrew     Rye,Colorado    andrew_brendon_tye@hotmail.com
                                                   4574478  
 Eddie      White Sulphur Springs,West Virginia
                            eddie.t@gmail.com      4678990 
"""
```

For now I tried :

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(str_test), delim_whitespace=True, header=[0])
```

Comment: you need to repair your file before passing it to `read_csv`

Comment: Any suggestions/references/links with regards to repairing such texts within report file? @RomanPerekhrest